# Scrolling to a element in bootstrap modal in web driver is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to close a bootstrap modal through Web driver script.The modal has Close button at the bottom.I am trying to scroll to the element and then click on the element but it is not working.when used `moveToELement(toElement)` method the script is throwing

> MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Offset within element cannot be
>   scrolled into view:" exception

. So I have tried to javascript scroll method and another way.They didn't throw any exception but it also didn't work. Below is the code

```
        WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
        d.get("http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/");
        d.findElement(By.linkText("Modal")).click();
        d.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-target='#myModal']")).click();
        WebElement e=d.findElement(By.className("btn-default"));    
//using moveToElement
        Actions a=new Actions(d);
        a.moveToElement(e).click().build().perform();
//using js scroll
        JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)d;
        Point p=e.getLocation();
        int y=p.getY();
        int x=p.getX();
        js.executeScript("scroll("+x+","+y+")");
        e,click();
//another way 
        Coordinates coordinate = ((Locatable)e).getCoordinates(); 
        coordinate.onPage(); 
        coordinate.inViewPort();
        e.click();
```

Any suggestions regarding how to solve this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the reasons why your code is not working:

- You **haven't added the code for timeout (Implicit/Explicit)**, and that may sometimes result in an exception related to element not found.
- Lastly, the **class-name by which you are trying to locate the 'Close' button**, i.e., in fact **returning 13 different elements** (when checked using Firepath).

Below code sorts out all the above-mentioned problems and works too:

```
    WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
    d.manage().window().maximize();//Maximizing window
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Giving implicit timeout of 20 seconds

    //Navigating to the site
    d.get("http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/");

    //Clicking on the "Modal" Link text
    d.findElement(By.linkText("Modal")).click();

    //Clicking on the "Launch Demo modal" button
    d.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-target='#myModal']")).click();

    //Clicking on the Close button of opened Modal window       
    d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='myModal']//button[.='Close']")).click();
```

Comment: @Subh...maximize is not necessary...try your code without maximize it will work.

Comment: Thanks @VivekSingh for pointing that out.. Have edited the code above.. But, still it's an important aspect; maximizing the browser window for automation, that is.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is cause your element `Close` is under a modal dialog. So your className wont work cause there are multiple elements using that class both in modal dialog and html. Try using xpath as:

```
.//*[@id='myModal']//button[text()='Close']
```

If you want to perform scroll also, you can achieve it by following code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("window.scrollBy(" + x + ","
            + y + ")", "");
```

Where x and y are co-ordinates of the element found through given xpath. Using the given xpath u need to only find that element and perform `element.click()`.